# Multimeter is showing wrong resistance

Tags: resistance, multimeter

I accidentally pluged my multimeter in a 220 v 50hz power supply keeping the knob on the resistance section. Now when I rotate the knob to the resistance part it always shows 24 ohms although there is no resistance I'm mesuring. What to do now?

Answer (score 4):

Buy a new meter.

You have learned a lesson but you will pay for it after the learning.

Comment: Isn't there any way to repair that? And did that really happened because of that fault or because of something else?

Comment: I think it's cheaper and safer to buy a new one.

Comment: You applied 250 V AC to a circuit that applies a couple of volts across a resistor to measure it. You have probably destroyed the measurement circuit. It is very unlikely that you can repair it and you didn't supply the make and model. In any case, repair questions are off-topic on this site unless the question shows good hardware debugging skills.

Comment: @AbhirupBakshi, `is it because of something else?` .... did you say anything about doing something else to the meter?